# css, clicking on something under a div

Tags: css, html, clicking

Alright, so I have some code, and I'd like to be able to click things under the div on top. For some reason, it isn't working, and I have no idea why. After extensive googling, I'm pretty sure I'm using pointer-events correctly, so if anyone could provide some insight into my problem, a million hugs.

```
    <html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#profilecontainer{
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
#topdiv{
background-image:url('http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/7227/profilek.png');
width:621;
height:365;
z-index:3!important;
pointer-events:none;
}
#content{
height:75;
width:571;
position:absolute;
clip:shape;
top:270;
left:25;
z-index:-2;
pointer-events:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="profilecontainer"><div id="content" class=""><a href=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LlYs_s1494>Test clicker</a></div><div id="topdiv"></div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: not related to your problem, but you need to add px to your heights and widths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `&nbsp;` to `topDiv` because it isn't displayed otherwise.

Then add `position: absolute;` to `topDiv`'s CSS and it should work fine.

Relevant information on this:

[Click through a DIV to underlying elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680429/click-through-a-div-to-underlying-elements)

Don't forget to use the IE workaround.

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but I also removed `pointer-events: auto;` from the `content` div.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/2HC6h/. I was working on the same thing. here it is. @alex is right about position absolute. `&nbsp;` was not necessary though.

Comment: dear lord, thanks so much. i would have never thought that was the problem.